# A cleaner and more cross-browser way to check a JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working with an API, there is a value that is being stored as a variable(string type) that looks like this:

```
var majorValue = "some_major_name";
```

And then I want to check the above string value and compare it against a short list (group) of majors to load a related piece of HTML. I came up with this solution with `includes` but I am not sure if this is the cleanest/most efficient way:

```
if(majorValue.includes('Accounting') || majorValue.includes('Business_Administration') || majorValue.includes('BA_and_Accounting') || majorValue.includes('BA_and_Chemistry') || majorValue.includes('BA_and_Communication') || majorValue.includes('BA_and_Computer_Info_Systems') || majorValue.includes('BA_and_Economics') || majorValue.includes('BA_and_Sport_Management') || majorValue.includes('BA_and_Theatre') || majorValue.includes('Business_and_Visual_Arts')||majorValue.includes('Computer_Information_Systems')||majorValue.includes('Data_Analytics') || majorValue.includes('Economics') || majorValue.includes('Marketing') || majorValue.includes('Sustainable_Business')) {
  $('#internship').load(`./snippets/internship/Business.html`);
};
```

There should be a better way than writting a chunk of `includes` and `||` to check and load the HTML. Isn't it better to store the major values in an array and then check if majorValue is matching with one of the items in the `array` and if it does, then do something (load the HTML piece).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const something = [
  'Accounting',
  'Business_Administration',
  'BA_and_Accounting',
  // ...
  'Marketing'
];

var majorValue = "Marketing";

if (something.includes(majorValue)) {
  console.log("found");
  //$('#internship').load(`./snippets/internship/Business.html`);
};
```

Comment: This is much better and I think it is even faster, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Or the other way, use array for each of the candidates then find on it the item that is contained by your `majorValue`.

```js
const something = [
  'Accounting',
  'Business_Administration',
  'BA_and_Accounting',
  // ...
  'Marketing'
];

var majorValue = "Marketing and stuff";


var x = something.find(function(item) {
  return majorValue.indexOf(item)>-1
})

console.log("found at", x)
```

Comment: This works too but the values in majorValue are going to be exact matches with the items in the array